# Brasero needs mplex and mpeg2enc plugins to work

Tags: dvd, burning

I installed brasero using the snap store on my laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Now it says I need mplex and mpeg2enc plugins to work.

After installing I tried to burn a DVD.  When I clicked "Burn", a box popped up saying I needed to manually install mplex and mpeg2enc plug-ins.

I followed the instructions of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1464786) and ran the following commands without errors:

```
sudo snap remove brasero
sudo apt install brasero
sudo apt install libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 mjpegtools
```

Then I ran Brasero from the terminal and it said the same thing in the desktop page.  Also it gave the following 4 errors when running Brasero from the terminal:

```
(brasero:38058): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 19:59:27.343: attempting to add an interface (EggTreeMultiDragSource) to class (GtkFileSystemModel) after class_init

(brasero:38058): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 19:59:34.219: attempting to add an interface (EggTreeMultiDragSource) to class (GtkFileSystemModel) after class_init

(brasero:38058): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 19:59:54.569: g_dbus_proxy_call_finish_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed

(brasero:38058): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:59:54.569: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

I ran the new command, and terminal said the latest version was installed.  I restarted the computer, and then tried a different file to make sure it wasn't a bad file I was trying to write. Brasero still say it needs the same 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

Install Brasero with apt instead of snap.

```
sudo snap remove brasero
sudo apt install brasero
```

You can install the relevant encoding software with

```
sudo apt install libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 mjpegtools
```

Comment: I followed all three instructions, but when I ran Brasero from terminal it listed 4 errors

Comment: Just to confirm, did you still get the box which tells you to install mplex and mpeg2enc plugins?

Comment: Yes the same box still come up/

Comment: @Rick Try the command in the edited version

Comment: I did the new command, and tried a couple simple other things that I added to my question.  Still the same results.